# Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 25 declared in library [Wear App sub-manifest]

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, wear-os

I'm trying to add a wearable module to my existing android (min sdk version 16) app. 
If I run the app (release mode), I'm getting this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller
>   than version 25 declared in library [Wear App sub-manifest]
>   c:\workspaces\sampleapp\android\app\build\generated\manifests\microapk\release\AndroidManifest.xml
>   Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="" to force usage

I don't want to increase the minSdkVersion.
So how can I fix the issue without changing minSdkVersion of my app?

here are my gradle files:

**phone app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            [...]
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/"
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    [...]

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.0'
    wearApp project(':sample-wear')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**waerable app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    signingConfigs {
        config {
            [...]
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.0'
    provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.0'
}
```

*Note: The error occurs only with Gradle 2.3.0. Gradle 2.2.3 works as expected...*

Similar issue on code.google.com: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=232834

Comment: What about applying the suggestion `Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="" to force usage`?

Answer (score 6):

In your gradle file just update the minSdkVersion into 23

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 30
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.oaics.customer"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: not a solution as OP stated

Answer (score 2):

In case of Ionic project

```
preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19"
```

In Config.xml (Project directory) file set above field to the version required.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I made it work was:

1. Uninstall the android platform: `ionic cordova platform rm android`
2. Update the config.xml file at the root of the Ionic project: from

   `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />`

   to

   `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />`

I'm assuming that for OP's situation the value should be 25 and not 19 (in my case it was 19 in the error).

3. Add the android platform to the project again: `ionic cordova platform add android`

then prepare and build - should not return that same error anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it in file build.gradle this works for me.

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 33
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to Gradle issue, as your 'wearable'module has minimum `23` sdk, not 25.

Please check also `AndroidManifest.xml` of that module as it may contains  `uses-sdk:minSdkVersion` with '25'.

If there is no value, you can add it thereto override Gradle configuration value.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem using platform IONIC and CORDOVA. I solved this problem doing the following:

Check both files:

`[folder_your_app]\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`

and for example:

```
\Users\[your_user]\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\tbxml-android.aar\f0d6a971caeb6d952bf6b9b62464f2ab\AndroidManifest.xml
```

In first file check following line:

```
uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26"
```

and compare with folowing line of the second file:

```
android:minSdkVersion="16"
```

Adjust the versions and enjoy!